# How to remove MISRA C errors/warnings on bitwise operations in firmware?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, misra

I am using MISRA C 2004 standards in [Code Composer Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Composer_Studio). I am always getting errors with respect to bitwise operations during initialization of the peripherals.

In the compiler .h file, the definition is like this.

```
#define SFR_8BIT(addr)  extern volatile unsigned char addr

SFR_8BIT(REG1);

#define REG2  REG1
```

Now in my code, if I use

```
REG2 |= 0x01;
```

The MISRA C is popping out these errors:

> 1. Bitwise operators shall not be applied to operands whose underlying type is signed - #1393-D (MISRA-C:2004 10.1/R)
> 2. The value of an expression of integer type shall not be implicitly converted to a different underlying type if it is not a conversion to a integer type of the same signedness.

I don't want to change the compiler .h file, and I want to eradicate these warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, your `char` is 8 bits and `int` is (at least) 16. That means all values of `unsigned char` can be represented as (signed) `int`s. That, in turn, means in your expression `REG2 |= 0x01;`, your `unsigned char` will be promoted to `int`, then the `OR` operation carried out, then the result of that cast back to `unsigned char`.

If I'm not mistaken, changing your constant to an `unsigned char` should prevent that:

```
REG2 |= (unsigned char)0x01;
```

or:

```
unsigned char one = (unsigned char)0x01;

REG2 |= one;
```

Comment: Use uint8_t if you want no violation with 6.3 rule of MISRA C 2004. REG2 |= (uint8_t)0x01;

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
REG2 |= 0x01U;
```

?